# Add Extra Fee on Product Page Using Hook [Woocommerce]

Tags: addition, woocommerce-rest-api, extra, fee

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html','product_page_price_display', 9999, 2 );
function product_page_price_display( $price_html, $product ) {

    $orig_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
    $price_html = wc_price( $orig_price + 10 );   
    return $price_html;

}
```

Comment: You have to give more details about your question and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html' , 'product_page_price_display', 9999, 2 );
function product_page_price_display( $price_html, $product ) {

    $orig_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
    $price_html = wc_price( $orig_price + 10 );   
    return $price_html;

}
```

Comment: You have to tell more why this is an answer to your question